# Load pseudo-namespaced classes in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces

is that possible to use fake-namespaces to represent a non-namespaced classes?

example:

**file: bar/foo.php**

```
class Foo {} // without namespace
```

**file: vendors/bar/bar.php**

```
use Pseudo\Namespace\Foo;

class bar {
  public __construct() { 
    Foo::test(); 
  }
}
```

I've been trying to use `spl_autoload_register` and map the namespaces to directories, but it is working only with namespaced classes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your best bet would be to use Classmap

Comment: I've attempted with classmap, but still can't have a fake namespace :(

Comment: If pseudo-namespaces are a must proxying and saving the proxy with the required namespace will be the best bet, but do you really need to have them in first place?

Comment: What do you mean by proxy? How would I do that? and yes, I do need it cuz I'm refactoring huge project. it is mostly non-namespaced and there are many ocurrences of classes with same name :/